# What is the intent of subtracting a mask from its value?

Tags: algorithm, graphics

I have come across these two lines of code on an old video game but I'm having a hard time understanding what is the logic of doing so.

```
var x = imagePos.X - (imagePos.X & 0xFFC0);
var y = imagePos.Y - (imagePos.Y & 0x0100);
```

What it does is that it subtracts a mask from its value, -64 for the X axis and 256 for the Y axis.

It appears to be some sort of repositioning a picture according some bits being set.

Any idea of what is the intent of doing so?

Comment: I think `x - (mask & x)` is equivalent to `x & (~ mask)`

Comment: Basically, that would mean to avoid some region if I understand you correctly?

Comment: The `x` variable is going to be a number between 0 and 63. The `y` variable is either the same as `imagePos.Y` or 256 less than `imagePos.Y`. Neither line changes the image position. You need to look at how the code uses `x` and `y` to determine why those calculations are needed.

Comment: Thanks guys, mystery is deciphered, posted the answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters who led me to figure that one out!

Basically what it does is a modulo, wraps values to 0-63 on X axis, 0-255 on Y axis.

And it is used for generating texture UVs for texture pages that are 256*256 (pretty old game!).

64 because there are 4-bit textures, this is then shifted according bits per pixel, i.e. << 2.

The result is that you get UVs in the 0-255 range on both X and Y axis.

Finally, there is a texture page index computed so as to compute the final UV in the texture atlas.

Comment: You have to wonder why if they just wanted a modulo operation, they didn't write `x&63` and `y&255`, since that's simpler and doesn't require x and y to be in a particular range to work.

Comment: Just a guess but in that code, there is a lot optimization where they try to avoid expensive operators, e.g. shift right instead of divide by two and so on. And yes, quite some you scratch your head but then realize it was simpler than it looks.

Comment: but the simpler forms `x&63` and `y&255` are almost certainly faster and produce less code than the more complicated forms chosen.

Comment: Of course but it's been decades this has been written, so...